# How to use an inserted import within a typescript transformer

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

especially guys fiddling around with typescript transformers!

Let's assume I added the following import statement to a source file:`import { whatever } from "my-whatever";`
Now I would like to use the import `whatever`. E.g. call it in a class definition.

Is this possible within typescript transformers? I fear that something has to be considered regarding bindings.

It's basically the same for adding a function like: `function myFunction() {}`
Can this function then somewhere else be called like `myFunction()`.

Has anyone experience with this? I would appreciate any help or resources. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to use the import? I'm tryng to achieve exactly the same. I'm importing a function and then trying to call it with some extra params.